# Auto-login when I enter my password, not requiring pressing "Enter"?

Tags: windows-8, passwords, login

On Win8, you can chose a "Pin" mode, where you enter four digits. Without pressing enter, it will log you in if you enter the correct password.

Is it possible to do this with characters? The amount will be variable.

Comment: What you want isn't possible.  There are some disadvantages to `Pin Mode` mainly because of the length of the pin.

Comment: Is this now possible with windows 8.1?

Comment: No;  it's not possible

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible in windows 8.0, 8.1 and 10. Go to settings and furthur to lock screen settings and enable auto login.